# Principal Part of Laurent series' expansion of $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z^3)}{(1-\cos z)^3}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need to calculate principal part of the Laurent series expansion of $f$ at $z_0=0$ with 
$$
f(z)=\frac{\sin(z^3)}{(1-\cos z)^3}
$$

I can see that $f$ has a pole of order 3 at $z_0=0$ , and also that $f$ is an odd function, therefore the expansion will be $$ a_{-3}z^{-3}+a_{-1}z^{-1} $$ but after this I am stuck. I tried using some trigonomteric identities, but they seem to make things more complicated.

I calculated $a_{-1}$ using the residue formula and it seems to be 2 , but I think there has to be a simpler way to deal with this.

Any help or advice towards the soluution would be welcome.

Comment: Would the Taylor expansion help you ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The Taylor expansion of sinz comes in hand, but $(1- \cos z)^3$ results in its Taylor expansion raised in the third

Comment: Let me put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping that the Taylor series could help you to some extent, let us start with $$\sin(y)=y-\frac{y^3}{6}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ So  $$\sin(z^3)=z^3-\frac{z^9}{6}+O\left(z^{10}\right)$$ Now $$\cos(z)=1-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^4}{24}+O\left(z^5\right)$$ $$1-\cos(z)=\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^4}{24}+O\left(z^5\right)$$ So $$\frac{\sin(z^3)}{(1-\cos z)^3}=\frac{8}{z^3}+\frac{2}{z}+\frac{4 z}{15}+O\left(z^3\right)$$

Comment: This is very simple! Thank you! I didn't know that I could do this though. I thought that I had to calculate $(1-cosz)^3$ by taking the cauchy product of the series representation of $(1-cosz)$ with itself times 3 formally.

Comment: You are very welcome ! Binomial theorem was the trick ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How do you take the quotient between the two series?

Comment: @Javier. There are different ways : perform the long division (tedious) or search for the expansion of $x^n f(x)$, $n$ being such that there is a finite limit at $x=0$ or generalized Taylor.

Comment: For example, for $\frac{1}{ax^2+O(x^4)}$ what'd you suggest? Should I expand the Taylor series of $\frac{x^2}{ax^2+O(x^4)}$ and then divide by $x^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $1-\cos(z)=2\sin^{2}(z/2)$ so that

$$ f(z)=\dfrac{\sin(z^3)}{8\sin^6(z/2)}.$$

Thus, by means of the fundamental L'Hopital involving the sine function, there holds $$\displaystyle \lim_{z\rightarrow a}f(z)(z-a)^6=\frac{\sin(a^3)}{\cos^2(a/2)}$$ whenever $a$ is a zero of $\sin^{2}(z/2)$.

Therefore, the poles of $f$ are of order $6$.