# Fractions and big $O$ notation.

Tags: calculus, fractions, laurent-series

I need to find the principal part of the holomorphic functions:
$$
\frac{1}{1-\cos z},\,\,\text{in $z_0=0$, and}\,\, \tan z\,\,\text{in $z=\pi/2$}
$$
So using the Taylor series of $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ yields:
$$
\frac{1}{1-\cos z} = \frac{1}{\frac{z^2}{2} + O(z^4)}\,\,\text{and}\,\, \tan z=\frac{z+O(z^3)}{1+\frac{z^2}{2}+O(z^4)}
$$
I'm looking for an answer as the one obtained in the answer of:
[Principal Part of Laurent series' expansion of $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z^3)}{(1-\cos z)^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913751/principal-part-of-laurent-series-expansion-of-fz-frac-sinz31-cos-z).

I understand the basic ideas behind the notation, but since I've never used the $O$ notation before I'd like a somehow detailed explanation (as formal as possible, like how it matters the center of the Taylor series) and if possible a general method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us look at $\frac{1}{1-\cos z}$. Using your formula, you get:
$$ \frac{1}{1-\cos z} = 2 z^{-2} \frac{1}{1+O(z^2)} = 2 z^{-2} (1+ O(z^2)) = 2 z^{-2} + O(1).$$

For $\cot z$ at $0$ (use basic trigonometry to get to your question), you get:
$$\cot z = z^{-1} \frac{1+z^2/2+O(z^4)}{1 + O(z^2)} = z^{-1} (1+z^2/2+O(z^4))(1 + O(z^2)) = z^{-1} +O(z).$$

It might be useful to remember that $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+...$, so $\frac{1}{1-O(z)} = 1+O(z)...$ and $\frac{1}{1-z +O(z)} = 1-z+O(z)+...$ and so on.

Comment: Great, thanks for the quick answer! I see you're strongly using thefact that $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+\cdots$. What happens when the Taylor expansion is around a different point than 0?

Comment: Well, just translate everything... Whenever you need to expand $f(z)$ around $z_0$, instead expand $g(z) := f(z+z_0)$ around $0$. If $g(z) = ... z^{-1} a_{-1} + a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2+...$, you also have $f(z) = ... (z-z_0)^{-1} a_{-1} + a_0 + a_1 (z-z_0) + a_2 (z-z_0)^2+...$.

Comment: There's something that still troubles me. What does it mean $\frac{1}{1-O(z^n)} = 1+O(z^n)$ formally? Since $O(z^n)$ is a set of functions, are these expressions also sets? Or do we mean something like: 'If $f\in O(z^n)$ then $\frac{1}{1-f(z)} = 1+f(z)$ when $z\to 0$, and the expression is just an abuse of notation.'

Comment: I suppose it formally means that if $f(z)$ is $O(z^n)$ then $\frac{1}{1-f(z)} = 1 + g(z)$ where $g(z)$ is some function in $O(z^n)$ (and of course $g$ depends on the choice of $f$).

Comment: In the comment above, you can in fact take $g(z) = f(z) + O(z^{2n})$, meaning that $g(z) = f(z) + h(z)$ with some $h$ in $O(z^{2n})$.